# visual studio не видит hyper-v

Tags: android, windows, xamarin, hyper-v, android-emulator

Visual Studio 2019 Community не видит то, что на системе включен Hyper-V. Разрабатываю на Xamarin Forms, и при попытке запуска эмулятора Android вижу данное сообщение:
[image: Компонент Hyper-V не настроен]

И это при том, что на системе он полностью включен.
Вот скриншот:
[image: Компоненты Windows 10]

Система на Windows 10 Pro сборки 2004, процессор Ryzen 7 1700, 16 гб. оперативной памяти. Скриншот:
[image: О системе]
[image: О системе - диспетчер задач]

Что я сделал не так? В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите всё ли соблюдено для Hyper-V: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-requirements#verify-hardware-compatibility

Comment: @woesss, да, все условия соблюдены

Comment: В некоторых системах Hyper-V включается через Bios - проверьте он там включен?

Comment: @Barmaley да, точно включен

Comment: Имею такую же проблему. НА одном компе все работает на втором не видит hyper V но запускается. И видно что медленно? Решили проблему? Спасибо. И кстати тоже на райзен. На intel все работает.